# Is it possible to sign into one organisation only

Tags: github

If you are using a single GitHub for multiple organisations, is there a way to sign into a single organisation? Or sign into your "non-organisation" profile, without signing into any organisations? Say you don't want to sign into your work organisation from your personal machine.

Comment: Is this question about GitHub web?

Comment: yes it is @Raju

Comment: You are a member of an organization through your personal account, so singing in into your account effectively signs you in to all organizations it is a member of. Maybe you would prefer to have two separate accounts -- one for personal use, and one for membership in your work organization?

Comment: As explained by @GoodDeeds, there is no way you can restrict your login into certain organizations only as long as all these organizations are associated to a single email id/account.